# String subscript out of range error when reading from a JSON string C++

Tags: c++, json, string, subscript

I'm trying to make a function which returns the element of a JSON attribute.

```
string Json_obj::get_attribute(const string& attribute) {
    size_t found = body_.find(attribute);
    char eos = ',';
    string element;
    if (found == string::npos) {
        cerr << "Not found attribute" << endl;
    }
    else { //if attribute exists
    
        size_t found_trim = found + attribute.length() + 3; //start after first quote ' mark
        size_t c = found_trim;

        while (body_[c] != eos) {
            
            element = element + body_[c];
            c++;
        }
    }
    return element;
}
```

For example in the body: `"mrkl_root":"1234567890","time":123,"bits":456,`

`get_attribute("mrkl_root")` should return: **1234567890**.

Instead I get a string subscript out of range error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your proof that every time the function is called there will be at least three more characters after the attribute, and that there will always be a comma afterwards? Can you point to the exact line in the shown code that verifies that, before blindly assuming that this is true, and then running off the end of the string, throwing this exception, when it's not?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] (with hard-coded values and string contents), then use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring the values of variables. This should help you understand what's going in and hopefully also how to solve the problem.

Comment: Also, try to think of what happens when the JSON string would be, instead, `"1234567890":"mrkl_root","time":123,"bits":456,`? What do you expect `get_attribute("mrkl_root")` to do, in this situation?